SSIS package pending execution and Service SID support missing
Does anyone know what Service SID Support has been enabled on the service would mean? In regards to the SQL Server Repair utility fixing permissions issues for SSIS packages.
After a server restart/update, the SSIS packages we are running will no longer execute. Re-deploying the packages is prohibited due to "insufficient permissions" and all of the SSIS packages that should be running are stuck in the "Pending execution" state.
Thankfully, this issue can be easily fixed by running the SQL Server Repair utility. When doing so, the following warning messages are generated:

The following warnings were encountered while configuring settings on your SQL Server. These resources / settings were missing or invalid so default values were used in recreating the missing resources. Please review to make sure they don't require further customization for your applications:
Service SID support has been enabled on the service
Service SID support has been enabled on the service

I would like to figure out the root cause of this issue so we can stop running the repair each time the system is restarted. (Or perhaps script the repair to run after reboot?)
Does anyone know what Service SID Support has been enabled on the service would mean?
(SSIS Package Stuck in "Pending Execution" status)
I attempted to change the service sid status from "unrestricted" to "restricted" and "none" on the SSIS service account and on the SQL Server account, but it didn't recreate the issue like I hoped. I don't really want to delete the service account without a reliable way to get it back, but I would be willing to try.
Seems like there are a lot of similar articles/questions on here, but NONE of them detail exactly what permissions were added to exactly what account.

Lots of answers on here stating things like: " Oh it was just a GPO permissions issue" or "Permissions were removed so I added them back and now we're good to go." What permissions? What users?
